# Alternate row color for every 3 items?

Tags: php, background-color, alternate

I have a unordered list with 3 items in every row (instead of the default 1). Now I want to alternate the row colors. How would I do that?

So basicially I want to do something like this:

```
if ($listCount == 1, 2, 3 OR 7, 8, 9 OR 13, 14, 15) {
    $alternateRow = "rowOdd";
}
else {
    $alternateRow = "rowEven";
}
```

(I know this is a syntax error, just trying to explain)

I think it's possible with modulus but to be honest I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: Can you show us how you are rendering these *rows* please?

Comment: how are you outputting your lists, e.g. is the data pulled from a db using a while loop? The easiest thing I can think of right now is to use a counter, e.g. `$i = 1`, after outputting each list item do `$i++` and if `$i==3` then set `$i=1` again and add a class to the li e.g `<li class="rowEven>` then in your css '.rowEven { background-color: #ccc; }'

Comment: if ((($listCount - 1) / 3) % 2) == 0) "rowOdd" else "rowEven" should work for any number instead of having to list them out in a conditional. Starting at 0.. 0, 1, and 2 divided by 3 gives 0, which when divided by 2 leaves a remainder of 0. 3, 4, and 5 divided by 3 gives 1, which when divided by 2 leaves a remainder of 1. And so on, with alternating groups of three numbers giving 0 or 1 as the remainder.

Comment: Use CSS's `nth-child` property to do this sort of thing. Don't make your processing code so complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, modulo. You can test for `($listCount - 1) % 6 < 3`.

Comment: I think it should be $listCount - 1, because he's starting at 1 and 6 is supposed to be in the even group

Comment: @jonhopkins: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it completely with css?
http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 1):

Since the original poster was not clear on modulo I figure I would help explain how it works so that you can use it the next time something comes up that needs it. The Modulo operator (%) works by determing the remainder of a division between the two operands.

The rule for modulo is:

```
if left < right: left % right = left
if left > right: left % right = remainder of left / right
```

For example:

```
 - 1  % 6  = 1 ( 1 < 6 so the answer is 1    ) 
 - 7  % 6  = 1 ( 7/6 = 1 with remainder of 1 ) 
 - 10 % 6  = 4 ( 10/6 = 1 remainder of 4     ) 
 - 6  % 6  = 0 ( 6/6 = 1 with 0 remainder    )
```

So in your case you would get 123 (for 1,2,3 % 6 respectively) and 4,5,6 % 3 would give you 450. Then 7,8,9 % 6 would yield you 123 again, 10,11,12 would be 450 again, and so on forever. So your code would:

```
// check that list count is less than three but not = 0
// (only true when mod yields 1,2, or 3)
if($listCount % 6 < 3 && $listCount % 6 == 0){
  $alternateRow = "rowOdd";
} else {
  $alternateRow = "rowEven";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
 $Value = "rowEven";
while ()
{
  while (i < 3)
  {
    $alternateRow = $value
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  if ($value == "rowOdd")
    $Value = "rowEven";
  else
    $Value = "rowOdd"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use modulo like this:

```
<?php

$numRecords=9;

for ($i = 0; $i < $numRecords; $i++)
{
 $className = "";
 if (($i % 3) == 0)
 {
  $className = "third";
  echo "i = " . $i;
 }
 else
 {
  $className = "other";
 }

}
?>
```

Comment: This will get every third item. OP wants groups of three items.

Comment: Ah, sorry my mistake. I thought he wanted to alternate the row color on every third row instead of the one